# R: subsetting is not working, it's including values outside parameter

Tags: r

I am new to R and I have run into a problem. Overall, I am trying to make a time series plot using `ggplot2`. The data frame called `center` includes 16 csv(each with a header in the first row) that I read into R and combined using the code below:

```
files<-list.files("path",pattern="*csv", full.names=T)
names(files)<-files
center<- do.call(rbind, lapply(files, read_csv))
```

I did the above with no errors.

I want to subset `center` because it goes way beyond the time frame of the other `csv` files.

I used this code below and when I viewed the subsetted data, it included values from dates outside the parameters i wanted:

```
center_sub <- subset (center,
                       center$rtime >= "2016-10-28 12:40:00", 
                                      tz = "America/New_York"&
                       center$rtime <= "2017-02-14 06:30:00",
                                      tz = "America/New_York")
```

I did get any error from R studio, but when I`view(center_sub)`it had more dates outside my parameter.

I am not sure why it is including other dates, any kind of help will be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing some of your data. It could be the tz being different or something else. FYI you could specify directly in ggplot the limit of the axes e.g:  'scale_x_datetime(limits = c(ymd_hms("2017-01-01 00:00:00"), ymd_hms("2017-01-01 12:00:00")). So you could avoid using 'subset'.

Comment: @ed_sans Thank you! I tried the scale_x_datetime code and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Interestingly, you should have gotten an error since you use single equal sign, `tz = ...`,  denoting assignment instead of double equal sign, `tz == ...` to test logically for equality.